# Referencing SQL column generated from SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my SQL, I'm trying to basically see if my select statement (columns) are greater than zero. If so, then return the record, if not then it's not included with the results. here's my code:

```
SELECT 
  a.securityID, 
  username, 
  a.dateOn, 
  (SELECT SUM(pricePaid*qty) as total FROM auctions_cart c INNER JOIN auctions_orders o ON o.orderID=c.orderID WHERE o.securityID=a.securityID AND c.status='closed' AND o.dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND o.dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as aTotal, 
  (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM donations_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM' AND rDenied<>'True') as dTotal, 
  (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM events_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as eTotal, 
  (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM registrations_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as rTotal

FROM authorizeNet a 

INNER JOIN security s ON s.securityID=a.securityID 

WHERE 
  (a.dateOn is not null) AND
  (aTotal>0 OR eTotal>0 OR rTotal>0 or dTotal>0)
```

Things of note... the 3-6 columns are SELECT statements that filter based on the a.securityID in the zero column. At the end of the (SELECT...) I try to say as aTotal and then reference that in the WHERE clause. It's not working.

Comment: "It's not working" will not help us help you.  Not working how???  No result?  Error out?  Wrong result?

Comment: The easiest way around this would be a CTE or a correlated subquery of some sort.

Comment: I'm sorry... not working means it was giving me an error... aTotal not a column, rTotal not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.securityID, username, a.dateOn
    FROM authorizeNet a 
    INNER JOIN security s ON s.securityID=a.securityID 
    WHERE a.dateOn IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT cte.*, a.total AS aTotal, d.total AS dTotal, e.total AS eTotal, r.total AS rTotal
FROM cte 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(pricePaid*qty) as total 
    FROM auctions_cart c 
    INNER JOIN auctions_orders o ON o.orderID=c.orderID 
    WHERE o.securityID = cte.securityID 
        AND c.status='closed' 
        AND o.dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' 
        AND o.dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM'
) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total 
    FROM donations_cart 
    WHERE securityID = cte.securityID 
        AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' 
        AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM' 
        AND rDenied<>'True'
) d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total 
    FROM events_cart 
    WHERE securityID = cte.securityID 
        AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' 
        AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM'
) e
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total 
    FROM registrations_cart 
    WHERE securityID = cte.securityID 
        AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' 
        AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM'
) r
WHERE a.total > 0 OR e.total > 0 OR r.total > 0 or d.total > 0
```

Comment: wow... this really blows my mind and I have no idea how this works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference *aliases* of *aggregate columns* in your `WHERE` clause. If you want to preserve your query, what you can do is the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.securityID, username, a.dateOn, 
    (SELECT SUM(pricePaid*qty) as total FROM auctions_cart c INNER JOIN auctions_orders o ON o.orderID=c.orderID WHERE o.securityID=a.securityID AND c.status='closed' AND o.dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND o.dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as aTotal, 
    (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM donations_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM' AND rDenied<>'True') as dTotal, 
    (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM events_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as eTotal, 
    (SELECT SUM(price*qty) as total FROM registrations_cart WHERE securityID=a.securityID AND dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM') as rTotal
    FROM authorizeNet a 
    INNER JOIN security s ON s.securityID=a.securityID 
    ) B       
WHERE (a.dateOn is not null) AND (aTotal>0 OR eTotal>0 OR rTotal>0 or dTotal>0)
```

There is a more elegant solution for this but I leave that up to you to determine.

Comment: I'd suggest using a CTE for clarity and maintainability over a sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

You will not like this answer but to make it work you need repeat the sub-query in the where clause.

So where you have `aTotal>0` it will need to be changed to

```
(
    SELECT SUM(pricePaid*qty) as total
    FROM auctions_cart c
    INNER JOIN auctions_orders o ON o.orderID=c.orderID
    WHERE o.securityID=a.securityID AND c.status='closed' AND o.dateOn between '11/1/2019 00:01:00.00' AND '11/30/2019 23:59:59.999' AND o.dateOn>='7/2/2013 9:16:15 AM'
) > 0
```

Comment: LOL.... that's gonna be one long query. Actually, if thats the case, can i not have it in the main select statement? Just add that in the WHERE area without specifying it in the SELECT part?